# How can I create a button that links to a random page?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a button that links to a random page in my simple website. I'm having issues modifying the "href" and making it go to the page on the click.

Here is the JavaScript I have written:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
let arrayofpages = ["my_cat.html","about_me","art.html","index.html"]
let randompage = arrayofpages[Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayofpages.length)];

document.addEventListener("click",function(){
document.getElementById("lucky_btn").href = "${randompage}";
document.getElementById("lucky_btn").innerHTML = "random page";
});
```

Comment: "_${randompage}_" is not on your list, use the backticks instead of double quotes when writing a template literal.

Comment: thank you I made that adjustment but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: `.href = randompage`

Comment: Please don't edit the question according to the comments or answers, such an edit invalidates the existing answers.

Comment: Also, your code [seems to work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/fzvmso02/) with the backticks.

Answer (score 0):

The string "${randompage}" is literally just a string that says `"${randompage}"`. Instead, use backticks:

```
`${randompage}`  // This creates a string out of the variable randompage
```

But in your case, since you're not doing anything with the string, the simplest way is to use the variable directly:

```
document.getElementById("lucky_btn").href = randompage;
```

---

In general, template literals are more useful for inserting variables into a longer string, like

```
let name = 'Sarah';
let quality = 'great';
let message = `Hello ${name}, have a ${quality} day`;
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bug in your code. you used double quotes `""` instead of backticks ``` `` ```.

This line

```js
document.getElementById("lucky_btn").href = "${randompage}";
```

should be

```js
document.getElementById("lucky_btn").href = `${randompage}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the bug that was causing the issue, of not redirecting to a random page:

instead of

```
document.getElementById("lucky_btn").href = "${randompage}";
```

where I should have used backticks, I changed the code to:

```
 document.location.href = `${randompage}`;
```

and this has solved the problem!